# how to determine whether boost async_accept is listening on a port or not

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am unable to get this example working
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html

I have changed the port 13 to 1163 so that I don't need to be a root user to start listening.

And I am running the `io_service` in separate thread.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp_server server(io_service);
        boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
        t.detach();

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    string wait;
    cin >> wait;
    return 0;
}
```

When testing the above server with http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html client, it says `connection refused`.

`netstat --listen` didn't show any open ports on 1163

I couldn't figure out how to use `boost::asio::async_result<typename Handler>` I am confused on `Handler`.

**Working modification**

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp_server server(io_service);
        boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
        t.detach();
        string wait;
        cin >> wait;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the `wait` is inside the `try` block, the code working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If asio can't listen on the port the creation or binding of the `acceptor` will already fail. In your case you are creating the acceptor with `acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13))`, which is this overload: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor/overload3.html

This will directly try to bind the socket and throw an exception if that fails. The alternative (which is described on the bottom of this page) is to create the socket without an assigned endpoint and call `open` and `bind` on it, where `bind` will fail with an error (e.g. if the socket is already in use). In any case you won't need to wait for `accept/async_accept` to see an error.

I guess your issue is in the client program, which still tries to connect to port 13. Have you changed it to use port 1163? In the example code the port is not directly written, but a well-known service name is used here: `tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");`. The "daytime" reference will tell the resolver to use port 13.

**Update:** Now that that I see the actual code with the thread it's a totally different error:

If the `wait` is not inside the try block the asio `io_service` and `tcp_server` will go out of scope nearly immediatly, which means their destructors are called. This will stop all communication. Even worse, the detached thread now operates on some dangling pointers. As a general rule asio objects (the io_service eventloop, sockets, etc.) should all live in the the thread that uses them. The lifetime of the `io_service` should be tied to or shorter than the lifetime of a thread. The lifetime of the sockets should be shorter than that of the eventloop (`io_service`) that runs them. Other usage scenarios might be possible by using `shared_ptr`'s or by putting a lots of thoughts into the design, but that's not what I would recommend.

Comment: I have changed "daytime" to "1163"

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention about running in separate thread as I've taken it as trivial. I have updated actual test scenario. thank you.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a totally different error and scenario. Updated my answer to cover it.

Comment: thats an embarrassing question! should I delete it?

Comment: hey! but you didn't answer my question about using `boost::asio::async_result<typename Handler>`